# Getting filtered data in search bar from json

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uisearchbar

I'm having a name assigned to my name textfield like so..

```
for asd in orderDetails {

    if let jsonStr = asd.value(forKey: "customerJson") as? String {

        let data = sdf?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any] {
                for item in json {
                    if item.key == "first_Name" {
                        cell.nameLabel.text = item.value as? String //ASSIGNED HERE
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to search on the search bar based on this name. While searching in other views where the core data attributes were mentioned directly I did something like so which worked fine..

```
    filtered = self.newProdDetails.filter({( data : NewProduct) -> Bool in
        return (data.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! //Here the entity NewProduct has an attribute name
    })
```

But in the current scenario, the attribute is a called `customer_json` which is a json string like so..

```
customer_json={
  "mobile_number”:”9876543210”,
  "first_name”:”testName”,
  "last_name”:”testLastName”,
  "seller_id":"93"
}
```

How can I mention `first_name` in the search parameter

Answer (score 0):

1. It's bad idea to keep working with Data object or even JSON string directly as your Model. I recommend you to create few Structs, make the conform to Codeable  protocol, so I will make the easy to work with and easy to convert into JSON whoever you want. I'm strongly advice you to consider it.
2. `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:)` converting your data into Dictionary, so instead of enumerating it you can access value you want by key:

Like this:

```
 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any],
    let name = json["first_Name"] {
     cell.nameLabel.text = name
 }
```

And definitely you can access you data same way:

```
 orderDetails.filter{ asd in  
    if 
        let jsonStr = asd.value(forKey: "customerJson") as? String,
        let data = sdf?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any],
        let name = json["first_Name"],
        name == cell.nameLabel.text { 
             return true 
   } else {
       return false
   }
}
```